# Shiny App shows "undefined", UI appears on reload

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a rather complicated shiny app which successfully runs locally. 
Previously it was also successfully dockerized and ran ok in VirtualBox VM (Debian x64) via shinyproxy.

With the last docker images re-build the app does not work properly any longer, the container runs, log files show that the app starts,
however there is no UI, just 'undefined' in browser. After the reload in browser the app UI appears.

For easier troubleshooting I have replaced my complicated app with small demo-app, leaving the Dockerfile the same,
with lots of used in my complicated app libraries.

The demo-app consists of server.R, ui.R and global.R

I have the same strange result: 'undefined' instead of UI, the app appears after reload.

If I move all the libraries to server.R and delete global.R, then the problem is solved, the app UI appears immediately.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with R
FROM openanalytics/r-base 

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libgdal-dev \
    libproj-dev


RUN R -e "install.packages(c('remotes', 'RPostgreSQL', 'stringi', 'shiny', 
'shinydashboard',  'shinyjs', 'leaflet', 'plyr', 'dplyr', 'data.table', 
'scales', 'rgdal', 'sp', 'shinyBS', 'devtools','DT','rgeos','shinyjqui'), 
repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN installGithub.r hadley/ggplot2

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('tidyr', 'hexbin', 'purrr'), 
repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN installGithub.r ropensci/plotly 
RUN rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    default-jre \
    default-jdk \
    libv8-3.14-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rhandsontable', 'V8'), repos='https://cloud.r-
project.org/')"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    r-cran-rjava

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rJava', 'xlsxjars'), repos='https://cloud.r-
project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('xlsx'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

RUN installGithub.r jrowen/rhandsontable
RUN installGithub.r dreamRs/shinyWidgets
RUN rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/


RUN mkdir /root/test_app2
COPY test_app2 /root/test_app2

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e shiny::runApp('/root/test_app2')"]
```

server.R

```
    server <- function(input, output) {

      datasetInput <- reactive({
        switch(input$dataset,
               "rock" = rock,
               "pressure" = pressure,
               "cars" = cars)
      })

      output$summary <- renderPrint({
        dataset <- datasetInput()
        summary(dataset)
      })

  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })
```

}

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                  label = "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      numericInput(inputId = "obs",
                   label = "Number of observations to view:",
                   value = 10)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
      tableOutput("view")

    )
  )
)
```

global.R

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(stringi)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(scales)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(shinyBS)
library(rhandsontable)
library(xlsx)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(reshape2)
library(tools)
library(DT)
```

Can anyone help please?

Update: Minimized Dockerfile with the same problem:

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libgdal-dev \
    libproj-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages(c( 'shiny','dplyr'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

RUN rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    default-jre \
    default-jdk \
    libv8-3.14-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    r-cran-rjava

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rJava', 'xlsxjars'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('xlsx'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

RUN rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/

RUN mkdir /root/test_app2
COPY test_app2 /root/test_app2

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e shiny::runApp('/root/test_app2')"]
```

Having only three libraries - `shiny, xlsx, dplyr` - produces the same `'undefined'` result. But only on the first container run after the build, then the app runs ok (with login/logout, restarting docker service and shinyproxy service). Combinations `shiny & xlsx` or `shiny & dplyr` do not result in `'undefined'`

Comment: I have not seen something like this using a similar stack of packages but using `rocker/r-ver` as base. Can you try to reduce the number of loaded/installed packages to produce a minimal example?

Comment: If I comment out `library(xlsx)` in global.R the problem resolves in my simplified demo-app but not in my complicated app.

Comment: And the opposite question? Which packages are not needed to produce the error?

Comment: I have a rather strange result. Excluding these combinations of two libraries makes everything ok:  dplyr, xlsx / dplyr, ggplot2 / xlsx, ggplot2

Comment: Can you update your question to include such a minimal Docherfile and Shiny app?

Comment: I was not changing my Dockerfile, only the combinations of the above mentioned libraries were commented out in turns in `global.R`. I did restart the docker service and shinyproxy service with every change to `global.R`

Comment: Then please reduce the Dockerfile to what is necessary to reproduce the problem, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @Ralf Stubner's for the idea on minimazing the problem.

In the update to my post there's minimal Dockerfile which reproduces the problem. However, this problem exists only in the VirtualBox VM, everything runs fine (with the simplified example app and with my complex app) on the AWS. So, there's an issue in building a Docker image of the Shiny App in VirtualBox VM - the problem is rather different now.